# Unable to locate element error

Tags: element, watir

I am getting an error when trying to click a "Sponsors" link on the page:

```
unable to locate element, using {:href=>"/Sponsors", :target=>"", :tag_name=>"a"}
```

Here is the line I am using:

```
browser.div(:class => "pageContainer").header(:class => "page-header")
.div(:class => "container").nav.ul(:class => "nav nav-pills")
.li(:class => "", :index => 2).a(:href => "/Sponsors", :target => "").click
```

(FYI:  I've tried using index 0 through 4, and removing the index; all resulted in the same error)

Below is the code:

```
<div class="pageContainer">
    <header class="page-header">
        <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class>...</li>
                <li class>...</li>
                <li class="dropdown open">...</li>
                <li class>
                    <a href="/Sponsors" target"">
                            Sponsors

                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">...</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Is the link possibly in a frame or being loaded asynchronously? Does `browser.a(:href => "/Sponsors").click` (or even `browser.a(:text => "Sponsors").click`) work?

Comment: Both those worked.  Being new to Watir/Ruby, I thought I had to give the whole path to the element.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Posting as an answer since OP indicates that it's a solution.

Instead of qualifying the whole path to the element, use a single locator (which should still locate the element and should be less fragile if ancestor elements are changed):

```
browser.a(:href => "/Sponsors").click 
browser.a(:text => "Sponsors").click
```